# Syntax Error on SQL err no : 1064

Tags: php, mysql

I am up the creek, The following is my code, I have double checked the tables and the spelling of these tables they look correct, I keep getting the following error code when I try and submit my for to the SQL,

```
 insert into lbs_trace_etrack set 27827910119, Trevor Ackermann, TEST, Elspark, Trevor,   
 1234, Trevor, on, Testing, lbs_msisdn = '27827910119', lbs_agent = 'Trevor Ackermann', 
 lbs_client = 'TEST', lbs_station = 'Elspark', lbs_io = 'Trevor', lbs_case = '1234', 
 lbs_for = 'Trevor', lbs_permision = 'on', lbs_type = 'Testing', lbs_date = '2013-11-
 29', lbs_time = '14:44:59', lng = '', lat = '', distance = '', msisdn = '', result = 
 '', lbs_reason = ''Array ( [lbs_msisdn] => 27827910119 [lbs_agent] => Trevor Ackermann 
 [lbs_client] => TEST [lbs_station] => Elspark [lbs_io] => Trevor [lbs_case] => 1234 
 [lbs_for] => Trevor [lbs_permision] => on [lbs_type] => Testing [lbs_reason] => 
 Testing site and the functions [lbs_submit] => Trace )
```

Error is:

```
 You have an error in your SQL 
 syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
 syntax to use near '27827910119, Trevor Ackermann, TEST, Elspark, Trevor, 1234, 
 Trevor, on, Testing,' at line 2mysql err no : 1064
```

This is my action PHP

```
 //database settings
 $host = "localhost"; // Host name 
 $username = "stingin_epanic"; // Mysql username 
 $password = "*****"; // Mysql password 
 $db_name = "*****"; // Database name 

 //Drawn from Form Information used to Update Database
 $lbs_msisdn = $_REQUEST['lbs_msisdn'];
 $lbs_agent = $_REQUEST['lbs_agent'];
 $lbs_client = $_REQUEST['lbs_client'];
 $lbs_station = $_REQUEST['lbs_station'];
 $lbs_io = $_REQUEST['lbs_io'];
 $lbs_case = $_REQUEST['lbs_case'];
 $lbs_for = $_REQUEST['lbs_for'];
 $lbs_permision = $_REQUEST['lbs_permision'];
 $lbs_type = $_REQUEST['lbs_type'];
 $lbs_reason = $_REQUEST['lbs_reason'];

 //update database
 update_lbs($lbs_msisdn, $lbs_agent, $lbs_client, $lbs_station, $lbs_io, $lbs_case,  
 $lbs_for, $lbs_permision, $lbs_type, $lbs_reason);

 function update_lbs($lbs_msisdn, $lbs_agent, $lbs_client, $lbs_station, $lbs_io, 
 $lbs_case, $lbs_for, $lbs_permision, $lbs_type, $lbs_reason)

 global $host;
 global $username;
 global $password;
 global $db_name;
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');
 $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$date = date("Y-m-d") ;
$time = date("H:i:s");
 $insertSuccessful = false;
 $new_msisdn = '0' . substr($msisdn, 2);
 if ($con = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)) {
    if (mysql_select_db($db_name)) {
        $sql = "insert into lbs_trace_etrack  set 
        lbs_msisdn = '".$lbs_msisdn."', 
        lbs_agent = '".$lbs_agent."', 
        lbs_client = '".$lbs_client."',
        lbs_station = '".$lbs_station."', 
        lbs_io = '".$lbs_io."',
        lbs_case = '".$lbs_case."',
        lbs_for = '".$lbs_for."', 
        lbs_permision = '".$lbs_permision."',
        lbs_type = '".$lbs_type."',
        lbs_date = '".$date."',
        lbs_time = '".$time."',
        lng = '".$long."', 
        lat = '".$lat."', 
        distance = '".$dist."',
        lbs_result = '".$response."',
        lbs_reason = '".$lbs_reason."'"
        ;    
if (mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
            $insertSuccessful = true;
        } else {
            echo $sql;
            print_r($_POST);
            echo "\n" . mysql_error($con);
            echo "mysql err no : " . mysql_errno($con);
        }
        $sql1 = "insert into lbs_log set 
        lng = '".$long."', 
        lat = '".$lat."', 
        distance = '".$dist."',
        lbs_msisdn = '".$lbs_msisdn."', 
        date_time = '".$today."', 
        result = '".$response."',
        date = '".$date."',
        lbs_agent = '".$lbs_agent."',
        lbs_client = '".$lbs_client."'" ;
if (mysql_query($sql1, $con)) {
            $insertSuccessful = true;
        } else {
            echo $sql1;
            echo "\n" . mysql_error($con);
            echo "mysql err no : " . mysql_errno($con);
        }
        }
        $sql2 = "Update TEST_credits set credits=credits-1 Where account_nr=1";
        if (mysql_query($sql2, $con)) {
            $insertSuccessful = true;
        } else {
            echo $sql2;
            echo "\n" . mysql_error($con);
            echo "mysql err no : " . mysql_errno($con);
        }
    }


  return $insertSuccessful;
 }
```

sql is giving the problem sql1 and sql2 strings are working great

Any help appreciated

Comment: Insert syntax is : `insert into table (col1, col2) values (1,'A')`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You are trying to insert array `lbs_reason = ''Array ( [lbs_msisdn] => `

Comment: Well...there is a 'set' in an 'insert into'...thats new.

Comment: Ok I have found the problem the code is working fine I know about mysql_* the problem was I was updating the code in reamweaver and uploading the wrong file. Thanks all. Realy feel dumb now

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect,use either :

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...)
```

or

```
INSERT INTO table SET col1 = val1,col2 = val2, ...
```

You are missing the column names.

NOTE: Your PHP code does not match the SQL statement you provided. Can you explain that.